# How to parse commandline args with yargs in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, yargs

Here is what I tried (code adapted the code from the example in the yargs github readme):

```
// main.ts

import {Argv} from "yargs";


console.info(`CLI starter.`);

function serve(port: string) {
    console.info(`Serve on port ${port}.`);
}

require('yargs')
    .command('serve', "Start the server.", (yargs: Argv) => {
        yargs.option('port', {
            describe: "Port to bind on",
            default: "5000",
        }).option('verbose', {
            alias: 'v',
            default: false,
        })
    }, (args: any) => {
        if (args.verbose) {
            console.info("Starting the server...");
        }
        serve(args.port);
    }).argv;
```

Results:

```
npm run-script build; node build/main.js --port=432 --verbose

> typescript-cli-starter@0.0.1 build /Users/kaiyin/WebstormProjects/typescript-cli-starter
> tsc -p .

CLI starter.
```

Looks like yargs has no effects here.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: Where are you saving the argument matches?

Comment: Damn. I adapted from the official example: https://github.com/yargs/yargs#complex-example

Answer (score 14):

I adapted the code from the example in the yargs github readme, turns out it's not meant to be a complete example. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Anyways, I figured out how to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

import yargs, {Argv} from "yargs";

let argv = yargs
    .command('serve', "Start the server.", (yargs: Argv) => {
        return yargs.option('port', {
            describe: "Port to bind on",
            default: "5000",
        }).option('verbose', {
            alias: 'v',
            default: false,
        })
    }).argv;

if (argv.verbose) {
    console.info("Verbose mode on.");
}

serve(argv.port);

function serve(port: string) {
    console.info(`Serve on port ${port}.`);
}
```

You can find the complete `typescript-cli-starter` repo here: https://github.com/kindlychung/typescript-cli-starter

Comment: You are still importing 'yargs' twice. Consider doing `let argv = yargs.command(...) ...`

Comment: Yep, now fixed.

Comment: I tested with new versions of stuff and edited the answer accordingly. With the `* as yargs` form of import I was getting the error `cannot redefine property: default`. (Adding the error here in case somebody else is googling for that error and yargs). The correct way is to import the default export of yargs with `import yargs from "yargs"`.

Comment: Had to remove the `return` statement under the `.command` function to satisfy the typechecker, otherwise got a "No overload matches this call" type error. After that worked great!

Comment: After updating something, not sure what, the typechecker got angry if I didn't use the `ArgumentsCamelCase` type in my `.command` callback function definition when destructuring the arguments, so had to specify it like `({ port }: ArgumentsCamelCase<{ port: string }>) => {}`

Answer (score 7):

a minimalistic example

```
import * as yargs from 'yargs'

    let args = yargs
        .option('input', {
            alias: 'i',
            demandOption: true
        })
        .option('year', {
            alias: 'y',
            description: "Year number",
            demandOption: true
        }).argv;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
```

Answer (score 3):

An example including a command and callback function:

```
import yargs, { Argv, ArgumentsCamelCase } from 'yargs'
import { hideBin } from 'yargs/helpers'

yargs(hideBin(process.argv))
    .command(
        'select <color>',
        'Select a color to display',
        (args: Argv) => {
            args.positional('color', {
                describe: 'The color to display. e.g.) Blue to display blue'
            })
        },
        ({ color }: ArgumentsCamelCase<{ color: string }>) => {
            console.log(`Your color is ${color}!`)
        }
    )
    .demandCommand()
    .parse()
```